# PropertyСhanged по какой-то причине меняется на null.При реализации интерфейса через INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Я открываю окно через поток следующим образом.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        AskReplace ask = new AskReplace(to);
        ask.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

Где AskReplace это название окна.

```
public AskReplace(string userFileToReplace)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FileToReplace = userFileToReplace;
    ViewNameOfFile ="File "+userFileToReplace+"is exist do you want to replace it";
    PropertyChanged +=OnPropertyChanged;

}
```

Подписываю метод OnPropertyChanged на событие  PropertyChanged.
Сам метод выглядит вот так.

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FileText.Text = ViewNameOfFile;
}
```

Где FileText TextBlock который выглядит вот так.

```
 <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="0,144,0,63" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding viewNameOfFile}" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="FileText"/>
```

а ViewNameOfFile свойство типа string,которое выглядит вот так.

```
private string viewNameofFile;
public string ViewNameOfFile
{
    get
    {
        return viewNameofFile;
    }
    set
    {
        viewNameofFile = value;
        RunProperty("ViewNameOfFile");

    }
}
```

Свойство PropertyChanged я запускаю через метод RunProperty,метод выглядит следующим образом.

```
private void RunProperty(string propertyName)
{
    //PropertyChanged +=OnPropertyChanged; если я подпишу метод OnPropertyChanged здесь то всё нормально.Я конечно могу так сделать,но мне бы хотелось бы знать с чем это может быть связано.
    var handler = PropertyChanged;//в этом месте почему-то PropertyChanged равен нулю хотя я его проинициализировал в конструкторе.Подписав на него метод OnPropertyChanged.
    if (handler!=null)
        handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Подозреваю что это связано как-то с Dispatcher.Run() но не уверен в этом.

Comment: А какова цель этих махинаций?

Comment: Я создаю приложение которое сортирует музыку по тагам,обработку файлов я запускаю через отдельный поток,используя BackgroundWorker класс,чтобы можно было несколько обработок делать одновременно.Так как планирую переписать его в будущем под Web.А так как BackgroundWorker использует во внутренней имплементации пул потоков,который работает в режиме MTA.А поток который открывает новое окно должен быть STA я открываю окно AskReplace,через новый поток предварительно установив ApartmentState в STA.Если я правильно ваш вопрос понял.

Comment: как именно объявлен `PropertyChanged` и как именно вы его инициализуете в конструкторе?

Comment: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; объявлен он в теле класса,а метод подписывается при вызове конструктора.

Comment: `Binding viewNameOfFile`, кстати, неправильно, привязываться надо к свойству, а не к полю.

Answer (score 1):

Если нет особых завязок использовать рекомендую все же Task-и и async/await. BackgroundWorker-ы были еще при winforms и несколько устарели. Код получится проще и нагляднее. Что же касается окна, что бы выставить апартаменты потоку, то выглядит это странно, т.к. это можно сделать и без окна:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(MethodWhichRequiresSTA);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
    thread.Start(); 
    thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to end
```

И мне интересно, а зачем, собственно STA. Обычно обработка в фоне выполняется, а нотификация о выполнении и прочем уже в UI-потоке. К примеру:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Контекст асинхронной обработки Таска. Если нужны параметры — добавляй их в конструктор.
    /// </summary>
    public class BackgroundWorkerAsyncContext : IDisposable
    {
        #region Public Methods

        public Task<object> ProccessTrack()
        {
            var task = new Task<object>(() =>
            {
                //тут должна быть обработка какая-то.
                DateTime a = DateTime.Now;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - a).TotalMilliseconds);
                return new object();
            });

            task.Start();
            return task;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        #endregion Public Methods
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ViewModel нашего трека. Имеет имя, флаг того, что трек сейчас в обработке и соманду обработки.
    /// </summary>
    public class TrackViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private RelayCommand _compressCommand;
        private bool _isInProcess;
        private string _name;

        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Public Properties

        public ICommand CompressCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _compressCommand ?? (_compressCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //выставяем флаг обработки
                        IsInProcess = true;
                        //сама обработка
                        using (var context = new BackgroundWorkerAsyncContext())
                        {
                           var result = await context.ProccessTrack();
                           //result - выхлоп от таска, в данном примере  object.
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //что то с исключением сделать.
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        //убираем флаг.
                        IsInProcess = false;
                    }
                }));
            }
        }

        public bool IsInProcess
        {
            get { return _isInProcess; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _isInProcess)
                {
                    _isInProcess = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Properties
    }
```